# Size of nonlinear filter sequence to recover LFSR feedback polynomial

Tags: cryptanalysis, stream-cipher, lfsr

Let's suppose that there is a filter generator which based on $n$-size LFSR.

Denote a feedback polynomial as $g(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)$ and nonlinear filter function as $f(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)$.

Let $a = a_1, a_2, \dots, a_k$ be filter generator output sequence.

Attacker knows $f$ and $a$.

1. What are boundaries for $k$ to recover $g(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)$?
2. How to recover $g(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)$?

Comment: Need more information. There are a number of nonlinear modifications to LFSR(s) with nonlinear filters or combination generators.

Comment: Thanks you @kodlu for the answer and the description of the architectures of the generators. And, I apologize for the inaccurate wording, since I meant a non-linear filter generator. I'll add more info to the first post.

Comment: Define it more precisely since usually what's in the answer is what's called filter generator. Edit your question with math specification.

Answer (score 1):

For clarification, the linear complexity of a possibly nonlinear sequence is $L,$ then $2L$ bits are sufficient to determine the LFSR that will generate it, via the Berlekamp Massey algorithm. The list below examines some common types of nonlinear sequence generators.

**Filter generator:** *(supply more details in question please)*

The feedback function is linear (so an LFSR) but output is a nonlinear function applied to certain taps of the LFSR. There is a classical upper bound by Key, a lower bound due to Rueppel (*Analysis and Design of Stream Ciphers* book), as well as more recent results on the linear complexity of the output. The details can be quite technical to summarize, however.

Combination Generator:

Let there be $k$ LFSRs with pairwise relatively prime lengths $L_i,$ for $i=1,\ldots,k$ and feedback connections corresponding to primitive polynomials of degree $L_i.$ Then combine the outputs of these LFSRs, by means of a Boolean function $$
f:\{0,1\}^k\rightarrow \{0,1\}
$$
with nonlinearity $r.$ The nonlinearity of the function $f(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ is the highest degree of a monomial in its algebraic normal form. See [my answer to this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/47957/generate-anf-from-sbox) for more on how to determine the nonlinearity.

Then, the linear complexity of the output sequence resulting from this *combination generator* is given by $f(L_1,L_2,L_3)$ where the function is evaluated over the integers. See [the answer to this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/68578/how-to-produce-a-binary-output-sequence-using-lfsrs-but-with-increased-linear-co/68586#68586) for a specific example.

NLFSR:

The period and linear complexity of feedback registers with nonlinear boolean functions as feedback functions is unsolved in general but there are some partial results. There is a chapter "Nonlinear shift registers – A survey and challenges" by Tor Helleseth, in the book *Algebraic Curves and Finite Fields*, De Gruyter, eds Niederreiter et al. You can find a copy online if you search, but original is paywalled. Some of the methods there are closely related to deBruijn cycles.

Specific Designs:

There are some results on linear complexity of outputs of specific designs such as Trivium, Grain, Shrinking Generator (nonlinearity introduced by an algorithmic shrinking operation), Wikipedia is a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks. I saw Key's result about filter generator  in Algebraic Shift Register Sequences book by Goresky and Clapper. But I think formally it is another problem.