# Forward Security of Symmetric Encryption Schemes with LFSR based PRNG

Tags: public-key, symmetric, security-definition, lfsr, forward-secrecy

Forward security can be achieved using symmetric encryption schemes by combining with a pseudo-random number generator (PRNG). Does LFSR based PRNG provide forward security in this case?

Comment: The claim _"Forward security can be achieved using symmetric encryption schemes"_ is dubious and unsourced Also, _"LFSR-based PRNG"_ is vague. It goes from LFSR (very insecure) to [Trivium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivium_%28cipher%29) (unbroken), with [ASG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_step_generator), [SSG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-shrinking_generator), [A5/1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A5/1) in-between (unbroken for large-enough parameters, with no precise security claim).

Answer (score 2):

Once an attacker knows $2L$-bits of an $LFSR$ of length $L$ with unknown taps, they can use the [Berlekamp-Massey algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlekamp%E2%80%93Massey_algorithm) to construct your LFSR. If the taps are known, then only $L$ bits are required. Therefore your PRNG based on a single LFSR will fail. They were [popular](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/66698/18298) but anymore.

- LFSR's has no next-bit security. From previous known states, the next bit is exactly can be found.
- More generally, an attacker that knows the current state, they have more power than predicting the next outputs, they know the next states of your random number generator.
- LFSR's can be run backward, which will reveal the previously generated random numbers. Once an attacker accesses the system, they will able to decrypt the previously encrypted messages. See the [Double ratchet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_Ratchet_Algorithm) which is used by Signal.

Comment: @fgrieu I took the question like it only uses an LFSR. The OP must be clear about the algorithm as you noted on your comment.